# Using this.$router in a Laravel/Vue.js component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue.js component in Laravel, it's loading with:

```
Vue.component('user-profile', require('./components/UserProfile.vue').default);
```

However, when I use `this.$router.go()` in it, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$router' of undefined

So, I've add this to my `routes`:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/profile',
        component: UserProfile
    },
    ...
];
```

But then, I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: UserProfile is not defined

So, I replaced:

`Vue.component('user-profile', require('./components/UserProfile.vue').default);`

by:

`import UserProfile from './components/UserProfile.vue';`

But I get this error:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly?

How should I fix this issue to be able to use `this.$router.go()` in my component ?

=== EDIT ===

I'm using `this.$router.go()` here:

```
  methods: {
    async update () {
      await axios.put(`/api/user/` + this.data.id, this.user)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
          this.$router.go()
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  },
```

Comment: share code where you used `this.$router.go()` ?

Comment: @RishiRaut I've just updated my post.

Comment: as @RishiRaut said use arrow function and dont forget to register the `vue-router` to `vue instance` so that you can access `this.$router` as well as the current route as `this.$route`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either Use arrow function

```
methods: {
    async update () {
      await axios.put(`/api/user/` + this.data.id, this.user)
        .then((response) => { // check here
          console.log(response);
          this.$router.go()
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  },
```

Or use `var vm = this;`

```
 methods: {
    async update () {
      var vm = this;// check here
      await axios.put(`/api/user/` + this.data.id, this.user)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
          vm.$router.go(); // check here
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  },
```

[Read about arrow function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp)

Comment: Great! And thanks for the link about arrow function!